# Using DDMS to send KLM coordinates

Tags: android

I made a small test application that uses the GPS module. To test it, I used telenet to connect to the emulator and send geo fix coordinates.

Sending geo fix 90 90 from telnet made my application react ok.

After reading a while I found about the DDMS. There seems to be a problem with sending coordinates from it to the device. No matter what option I try: Manual or KML file (the KML loads fine) the device only receives one 0.0 and 0.0 coordinates, no matter what I send it.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that eclipse has something to do with locales of the computer. The solution to make it work was to force the eclipse to use en locales. So, find your eclipse.ini file and add this in the end of the file: **-Duser.language=en**

I recorded a path in google earth with the route I wanted to follow. I saved it. I converted it here: http://ge2adt.appspot.com/